# mongodb connection is not getting resolved in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to code refactor to ensure that mongodb instance is instantiated only once.

```
const dbs = async () => await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const mongoClient = new mongodb.MongoClient(dbUrl, {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    mongoClient.connect((err, client) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`err while connecting`);
          reject(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log('Successfully connected to db');
        return resolve(client);
    });
});
module.exports = dbs;
```

In my test.js I am doing as follow

```
const dbscl = require('./dbcon'); 
const setdb = dbscl.db(dbName);
```

I am getting error : dbscl.db is not a function . Any clue why dbs is not resolve as valid database connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting function as `dbs` but you are calling it as `db` in `dbscl.db(dbName)` and the other thing you are not exporting it correctly. Learn more about [how to export modules in nodejs](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-use-module-exports-in-node-js/)

You can export function like

```
module.exports = { dbs }

//Or
module.exports = { 
  dbs: dbs
}

//Or
module.exports.dbs = dbs
```

Now you can call your function like

```
const dbscl = require('./dbcon');
const setdb = dbscl.dbs('dbName');
```

Comment: when I log setdb it say : Promise { <pending> } and when I perform collection.insertOne it say isertOne is not a function...

Comment: should setdb = dbscl.dbs('dbName'); be dbscl.dbs.db('dbName') ????

Comment: just curious why you want to pass db name as parameter for connection ? do you want to use multiple databases ?

Comment: No, but I need to specific the db , where I need to insert data..

Comment: Try this `const setdb = await dbscl.dbs('dbName');`  when a function returns a promise you need to `await` for the promise to resolve